# Comparing Two Arrays with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying create multiple checkboxes using ng-repeat from Array1, and I'd like apply the "checked" attribute (using ng-checked) to certain ones depending if there is a match in Array2.

Here we have array1 in the controller:

```
$scope.possibleConditions = ["condition1", "condition2", "condition3", "condition4"];
```

and then array2 is from the same controller but via JSON API.

```
{
    "treated" : false,
    "data" : [{
        "conditions" : ["condition1", "condition2"],
    }]
}
```

This is my current ng-repeat set up in the template:

```
<p ng-repeat="condition in possibleConditions">                     
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{condition}}" />
    <label for="{{condition}}">
        {{condition}}
    </label>            
</p>
```

The desire is to apply the attribute `checked` to the input if, say, "condition1" in Array1 is found in "conditions" from Array2.

---

What I've tried:

**1:** I've tried using a filter (which I found on stackoverflow) after my controller:

```
.filter('customArray', function($filter){
return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
    if(arrayFilter){
        return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
            return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
        });
    }
};
```

with the ng-repeat amended slightly:

```
<p ng-repeat="conditions in possibleConditions | customArray:profileData.data:'conditions' ">
```

But that didn't work.

**2:** I've tried using another ng-repeat within the ng-repeat, then check it against the first one fir a match.

Example:

```
<p ng-repeat="conditions in possibleConditions">                    
    <input ng-repeat="condition in profileData.data[0].conditions | filter{condition == conditions}" type="checkbox" id="{{condition}}" />
    <label ng-repeat="condition in profileData.data[0].conditions | filter{condition == conditions}"  for="{{condition}}">
        {{condition}}
    </label>            
</p>
```

Hopefully somebody can help / point some guidance. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a filter here, simple [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive could work:

```
<p ng-repeat="condition in possibleConditions">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{condition}}" 
         ng-checked="response.data[0].conditions.indexOf(condition) > -1" />
  <label for="{{condition}}">
    {{condition}}
  </label>
</p>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fDn0niCCljo5wChzYiwa?p=info

where `response` is your data from API.

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! thank you for your quick response. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Glad it was useful.